# How to make git grep show at the top instead of the bottom of the terminal screen?

Tags: git, grep

Suppose my terminal screen is 40 lines high.

Suppose I type in "clear";

Suppose the output if git grep is only 1- lines.

Now, the desired output I want is to have the first 10 lines of my console be the output of git grep.

Instead, git grep fills in a bunch of blank lines and makes my output the *bottom* ten lines of the screen the output of git grep.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you looking for a way to have `git grep` not show its output through a pager?  Try:

```
GIT_PAGER='' git grep ...
```

`git grep` sends its output through a pager, which you can disable by setting the `GIT_PAGER` environment variable.  I think what you are seeing is your pager displaying the text at the bottom of the screen, rather than `git` doing so.  If this is not what you want, we need to know more about what's happening.

Answer (score 4):

Even if the question is a bit old, for further reference, I think the .gitconfig setting should be mentionned, here :

```
# ~/.gitconfig or .git/config

[pager]
  grep = false
```

This will ensure you never use pager when using `git grep`, without the need to add extra env variable.

Answer (score 1):

You could pipe the output through grep like so:

```
<git command> | grep -v '^$'
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting the GIT_PAGER Environment variable to '' will make all git commands output without the pager.

If you want it not to be paged only for a particular command, for example git grep, use it with `git --no--pager`